# Update second pie chart based on click event of first pie chart in Pentaho CDE

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, ccc

I am new to pentaho,
looking for a feature to update second pie chart by clicking first pie chart.

first of all, is this possible in pentaho cde?

if yes. could you share an example on how to use clikable property and clickaction property or by any other means?

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this documentation:

http://redmine.webdetails.org/projects/ccc/wiki/FAQ_Main_Changes_New_Features_CCC_v2#Handling-the-click-action

That should help you.

Comment: To that I add that your click action should Dashboards.fireChange("myParam", atom.value), and you should add the myParam to the listeners of the 2nd chart.